# Fatal:Class Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I didn't change any backend code .I dont know it triggers when I hit any url of laravel app it will show this error.I dont know why this happend and also need solution for this .My laravel version in 5.8 and php 7.2
 Fatal error : Class Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods C:\xampp\htdocs\pmf\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php on line 14 this is file it is saying.

Comment: Have you edited any code in your `vendor` directory? Try deleting the folder and re-running `composer install`.

Comment: Nope dear I didn't  ..I reverted all changes from last git commit but all in vain.I think local working directory has an issue ...I also delete vendor folder and hit composer update but nothing happened

Comment: @GeorgeHanson.. any solution .. ?

Comment: Then vendor folder is probably untracked from git. Delete the vendor folder and composer.lock and run `composer install`

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall or update composer wont solve the problem. In my case, you just need to restart the local development server, because the problem is just temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to restart the local development server.